# How to implement dynamic queries for MNesia?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I'm trying to implement a function that generates dynamic queries for MNesia.

For example, when function is called with these arguments;

```
dyn_query(list, person, [name, age], ["jack", 21])
```

I want to query MNesia to **list** items whose **name** is *"jack"* and **age** is *21* in **person** table.

I've tried to implement this by using qlc:q(ListComprehension) and qlc:string_to_handle("ListComprehension"). First failed because of compile errors, compiler didn't let me to use functions instead of ListComprehentions and variables instead of record names like "Item#Table.Field". Second failed, because erl_eval couldn't handle records and throwed exceptions like {undefined_record, person}.

Which method should I use? How could i solve these problems? Or should I use a different method?

Thanks.

Comment: records are compile time constructions which you cannot use in runtime dynamically. Basically at compile time all your records are converted into tuples looking like this {person, "jack", 21}. From this there is no way for the runtime to figure out what you are asking for when you say Item#Table.Field.

See http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html for more details on records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out match specs that [mnesia:select/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-2) uses for queries against a table. There is [mnesia:table_info/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#table_info-2) for finding out the column names (and column indexes) of a table.

Matchspecs are documented in [ERTS user guide on match specifications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html). I usually resort to using [ets:fun2ms/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#fun2ms-1) which is a handy parse-transform that can create a matchspec from erlang-looking fun syntax at compile time. You can play around with it from the shell directly.

Answer (score 1):

You might give "exprecs" a try. They are explained here:

http://forum.trapexit.org/viewtopic.php?p=21790

Reading from the description:

> The transform adds accessor functions
>   for instantiating, inspecting and
>   modifying records, without having to
>   introduce compile-time dependencies
>   between modules.

Examples are provided in that page. See if this helps.